# The probability of having 5 counters show red face

Tags: probability

There are $x$ counters , each counter has two face , one face is red and the other face is green.

Ahmed spreads the counters on a table and the number of counters that show a red face is $5$
He picks a counter at random and turns it over , the he picks at random a second counter and turns it over .
The probability that there are still 5 counters showing a red face is $\frac{19}{32}$ .Find the value of x .
My turn :
To have 5 counters showing a red face , the two chosen counters must be one red and the other is green
So
$\frac{5}{x} \times \frac{x-4}{x}$ + $\frac{x-5}{x} \times \frac{6}{x}$ = $\frac{19}{32}$

$x = 8$

Is this correct ?

Comment: It depends on what _then he picks at random a second counter and turns it over_ means. If it means that he can also turn the same counter twice then your work is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You nailed it.  A couple of comments:

As MathLover suggested, the problem is ambiguous.

However, if you assume that the $2$nd ctr is different from the first, then the equation is instead

$$\frac{5}{x} \times \frac{x-5}{x} \times 2 = \frac{19}{32}.$$

This implies that $$19x^2 - 320x + 1600 = 0,$$

which has no real roots.  So, the ambiguity can be *reverse-engineer* resolved, by presuming that $x$ must be real.

Further in the equation that you posted, there is a 2nd root of

$$x = \frac{400}{38}$$

which must be rejected, since $x$ must be an integer.

Problem is both tricky and poorly written.